# Hard drive management and replacement

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

1. How do I switch between partitions on my hard drive without restarting?
2. I got a new SSD that I want to put my OS on.  I don't want to image my old hard drive because I want to leave behind any malware on it.  My old drive has a recovery partition on it.  How do I get the OS from my old drive onto my new drive?

Comment: *"My old drive has a recovery partition on it."*  -- Read your PC's documentation.  There's probably mention of a program/procedure for making a set of installation DVDs or CDs.  If you have those discs, then you can easily re-install the Windows OS on a new disk drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone your recovery partition and the UEFI start partition, if you have one (it's a small 100 or 200MB partition) to the new drive, then disconnect the old drive while you reinstall from the recovery partition.

Be careful to preserve the partition sizes when cloning, so that you have free space left on your SSD on which to install windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what cloning software do you recommend?

Comment: I would suggest you use MiniTool DriveCopy ([link to the webpage for MiniTool](http://minitool.com/free-tools/minitool-drivecopy.html)). It is free, easy to use, and does what you need.

Comment: Minitool works great, but I'm still having trouble replacing the hard drive I created a new post labeled "Trouble installing a Hard Drive": [link](http://superuser.com/questions/837896/trouble-installing-a-new-hard-drive)